# SFill vs DD on linux (Comparing write speeds)

Tags: delete, dd

If I want to write zero's to empty space on a mountpoint using one pass is there any reason to use Sfill over dd?

With `sfill -l -l -z -v /mnt` I'm getting about 13mb/s write.

With  `dd if=/dev/zero | pv | dd of=/mnt/zero bs=4096` I'm getting atleast 100mb/s write.

Comment: I have used the `dd` method many times for this purpose, and it has worked without problems. You should check the time after flushing the buffers with the command `sync`. After that test you can select the fastest method. Please tell us the result :-)

Comment: Do you want this in order to make a compressed image file (as small as possible)? Or do you want this for privacy reasons (to make removed file data impossible to recover)? People have written that repeated overwriting is necessary, but nowadays there are many people who write that it is enough with one single overwriting instance. I don't know enough to tell what is correct concerning privacy. But I overwrite in order to make compressed images as small as possible.

Comment: @sudodus personal reason for use is to prevent data recovery with readily available software tools like Easus Data Recovery

Comment: Well, then I think speed is not the highest priority. So your decision depends on whether you think that data need to be overwritten more than once. Maybe it is better to be safe than sorry and use `sfill`, but *I don't think* tools available to you and me can recover data that are overwritten once.

Comment: @sudodus okay, but say I do 4 zero wipes with dd, that is still twice as fast as one zero wipe with sfill, so wouldnt the former be a better option (for my use case)?

Comment: They say that overwrites with random data is better at removing leftovers (weak magnetic patterns). In SSD drives, this is not relevant at all, and zeroing once is enough.

Comment: @sudodus I happen to use an SSD

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how reliable you want it. Generally: the quicker the zerofill the easier to restore it.

[sfill](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/eoan/man1/sfill.1.html) is part of the ATA Secure Erase command tool ([secure-delete](https://github.com/vanhauser-thc/THC-Archive/tree/master/Tools)) set and what `sfill` does is something like this ([source](https://superuser.com/questions/19326/how-to-wipe-free-disk-space-in-linux)):

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=zero.small.file bs=1024 count=102400
sync ; sleep 60 ; sync
shred -z zero.small.file
dd if=/dev/zero of=zero.file bs=1024
sync ; sleep 60 ; sync
rm zero.small.file
shred -z zero.file
sync ; sleep 60 ; sync
rm zero.file
```

This will probably be around 13 Mbs too. Use [-f](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/eoan/man1/sfill.1.html) option for a less secure but quicker zerofill by sfill.

Answer (score 0):

What about: ?

```
echo -e "If you dont have pv installed please remove the pv pipe in the for, or install pv\n\n"
zeropath="$(pwd)/zero.fill"
echo "Running $1 wipes, zero file written to $zeropath"

for wipes in $(seq 1 $1); do
  dd if=/dev/zero | pv | dd of=$zeropath bs=4096
  echo -e "Shredding $zeropath\n"
  shred --verbose $zeropath 
  rm $zeropath
done
```

Comment: 1. This is for hard disk drives (with magnetic memory). I am no security expert, so I should not decide if your script is good or bad; 2. For an SSD you need only create a file containing all free space filled with zeros and then remove it; 3. But beware, it is best to boot from another drive and use superuser permissions with `sudo`. Otherwise a few percent of the drive will be left for system processes to use, and sensitive data might sit there.

Comment: Added rm at the end, you can press control c if you have an ssd